# Storing Data That Must Be Used During Run-Time

Tags: c#, sql, performance, runtime

*Summary: How can I best store data that needs to be accessed during runtime (but not stored in memory), without making it difficult for others to edit the data?*

I've been looking into several different ways to store data that must be accessed during run time, but none of the solutions seem relevant to my issue. If after reading this you see another post that answers my question please just link me to it, I'll be glad to check it out.

I am in the process of creating a program to modify some video games. The main idea behind the app is flexibility when it comes to game updates. This means that I have to make the file where all of the addresses are stored easily accessible to everyone. At the moment I store the data in text files like so:

```
0x00000000 Description
```

My app then loads the text file into a dictionary list, using the first 8 (there is a check to remove 0x and make sure the value is able to be parsed) characters as a uint value, and the rest of the line is stored as the key (each key is unique, there is a check to ensure there are no duplicates). This worked fine in the beginning but there is an increasingly large amount of data being stored, and the app just cannot handle it. I get stack overflows, or the data just won't be stored. What I am wondering is how can I store the data so it can be efficiently accessed while the program is running? I have looked into sql databases but I am worried that people will have a difficult time editing them (including myself, I have only used an sql database once), or the performance might be slow. If this isn't the case I would appreciate just a small example of how it could be done. Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Here is the current code used to load the info (I don't think it's needed but if you want to take a look at what I'm doing here you go)

```
       using (r)
    {
        int counterSuccess = 0;
        int counterFailed = 0;

        while ((origString = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (origString.Length >= 8)
            {
                if (origString.StartsWith("0x", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    origString = origString.Substring(2);
                }
                parseSuccess = uint.TryParse(origString.Substring(0, 8), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out addr);
                addrIdentifier = origString.Remove(0, 8);
                addrIdentifier = addrIdentifier.Trim();
                    if (!parseSuccess)
                    {
                        counterFailed++;
                    }
                    else if (parseSuccess)
                    {
                        Addresses.Add(addrIdentifier, addr);
                        counterSuccess++;
                    }
                }
            }
        r.Close();
```

Comment: Use a database. Create a management software that allows the users to adjust the data comfortably.

Comment: Agreed with the database. Another option could be XML (possibly loading multiple files)

Comment: @meilke Meaning SQL, Access or just any general type?

Comment: @user2795977 Excuse the non-specific answer: That depends on so many things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a SQL or Access Data Base. They are pretty easy to handle, even for a  beginner. Other people have no problem editing them and their performance is beyond your imagination. You could export whatever kind of data you want very easily with a little code snippet (for example to text or CSV). You just need to learn basic SQL queries and some easy C# code to use them. You probably could find a beginner Database program in many general books teaching C# and also [MSDN examples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/). I myself learned database programming by Deitel & Deitel Visual Basic 6 How to program :). Don't try that, it was long before. For basic examples in C# or any language you could check [planet-source-code.com](http://www.planet-source-code.com). Welcome to the powerful world of database programming and SQL.